# Extract multiple iso files to one directory

Tags: iso, 7zip, unzip

I have downloaded a CD that is divided into 3 .iso files

I want to extract the three as one folder

I tried to do 7z on it but it fails and I couldn't figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: How you tried 7z?

Comment: yes i was doing it wrong .. every thing is okay now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-o` (output destination) switch to `7z` and possibly `-t` (archive type). A common mistake is to put a space after `7z` switches, which will cause the command to fail. Use the `x` option to extract with full paths. Install 7zip if you don't have it:

```
sudo apt install p7zip-full
```

You can specify the same output directory for each iso. The below commands assume you want to call the output directory `outdir` so adjust as needed.

The following command is for split archives that need to be recombined, which may apply in your case - try this first (replace `name-of.iso` with name of the first file):

```
7z x name-of.iso -tsplit -ooutdir
```

It that errors out `cannot process file as archive` or similar, then the files are not from a split archive. To extract them, for each file you can do

```
7z x name-of.iso -ooutdir
```

Or (useful if you have many files) you could use a `for` loop to extract all of them at once:

```
for f in *.iso*; do 7z x "$f" -ooutdir; done
```